# Linkbutton click in a asp:GridView cell does not trigger OnRowCommand event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asplinkbutton, rowcommand

**UI Feature**: I have a `GridView` with few columns. Most important column is **PcCode**, which shows a `string` value for each row.

**Expected**: When I click on one of the cell from a row of that PcCode column another `GridView` should be displayed. However, when I am trying to use a `asp:LinkButton` for a cell, things just don't work. `RowCommand` does not get triggered when I click on a `asp:LinkButton` in the `GridView` cell. Where am I doing things wrong? Which way the expected functionality can be achieved? Thanks in advance for helping out a newbie.

In the following code I was trying to get a `RowIndex` and pass it through the `CommandArgument` and use a `CommandName`.

.aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="_UIProfitcenterTotalGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="22" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ProfitcenterCode" EnableViewState="False" 
    OnRowDataBound="_UIProfitcenterTotalGridView_RowDataBound"
    OnPageIndexChanging="_UIProfitcenterTotalGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
    OnRowCommand="_UIProfitcenterTotalGridView_OnRowCommand">
    <Columns>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PcCode" InsertVisible="False" 
            ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="ProfitcenterCode" FooterText="Total" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="_UIPCCodeLinkButton" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProfitcenterCode") %>'  
                CommandName="Select" 
                CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex  %>'>
               </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
...
```

code behind for aspx.cs

```
 protected void _UIProfitcenterTotalGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = _UIProfitcenterTotalGridView.Rows[index];
            string ProfitcenterCode = _UIProfitcenterTotalGridView.DataKeys[_UIProfitcenterTotalGridView.SelectedIndex].Values["ProfitcenterCode"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

After the row is selected I need to take the selected row's value as a string and compare with a listitem to show a new GridView.

**Tried**

- Using Link_Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) and the following but failed.

  protected void _UIProfitcenterTotalGridView_RowCommand(object sender,   GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.CommandName == "Select")
          {string ProfitcenterCode =  ((GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)).Cells[2].Text;
          }
      }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use `LinkButton_Click()` event instead of `RowCommand` as [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15255819/1108500) suggested:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton button = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)button.NamingContainer;
        if (row != null)
        {
          string theValue = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument.ToString();
          ...
          ...
          //code for the extra thing I needed to do after selecting a cell value.
        }
     }
```

However I still had the problem, which I figured out. The problem was the `LinkButton` was not binding to the rows thefore, it could not pass any value on selection. What was missing was the following code:

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
                linkButton.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; //value of the first column from the grid 
                linkButton.Enabled = true;
                linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click); //triggering the LinkButton event here. 
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(linkButton);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sender object ( the link button that calls the event) and get the parent row from the gridview.  Example:

```
Protected Sub linkButton_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   'First cast the sender to a link button
   Dim btn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
   'now, if there is a command arguement, you can get that like this
   Dim id As String = btn.CommandArgument
   'to get the gridviewrow that the button is on:
    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)   

End Sub
```

It was hard to follow exactly what you were looking for, so if i missed something let me know and I will add it.

```
protected void linkButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //First cast the sender to a link button
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    //now, if there is a command arguement, you can get that like this
    string id = btn.CommandArgument;
    //to get the gridviewrow that the button is on:
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

}
```

And change your linkbutton to:

```
 <asp:LinkButton OnClick="linkButton_click" ID="_UIPCCodeLinkButton"
 runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProfitcenterCode") %>'

            CommandName="Select" 
            CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex  %>'>
```

Comment: I was looking for how to select a row value form the GridView on a LinkButton click.I have tried linkButton_Click event and it does not recognize since it is only client side check.I needed to postback to the server and sorry I have no clue about VB. I just needed to know the way I am doing it is correct or not. If not then which way is correct? LinkButton_Click event or OnRowCommand event?

Comment: You can easily translate c# to vb.net (or vb.net to c#) easily.  http://converter.telerik.com/.  It looks like the way you have it set up, you will need to use the click event.  You need to add the event handler to the link button.  Ill post a version in c#

Comment: Does this mean I need to use both linkButton_Click() and OnRowCommand()? However, using _Click event gives Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.displaycountries_aspx' does not contain a definition for '_UIPCCodeLinkButton_Click' and no extension method '_UIPCCodeLinkButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.displaycountries_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My example uses  linkButton_Click().  You can chose to use it as well.  Look at the code I gave you.  The linkbutton has an ONClick event that calls the method i posted.  Try to use that

Comment: I tried your snippet but unfortunately linkButton_Click() does not get triggered at all.